# Go to new php page

Tags: php, forms, button, hyperlink

I'm wondering the best way to go to a new page.  I have a PHP document with a submit button. Once that button is pressed, it runs the php code on that page, creates some session variables, then I want it to go to the next page after this code is executed.  I know with traditional submit buttons you simply have the form that's run being the next page, but how do I link it differently?

Comment: Are you looking for the [Location header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)?

Comment: If you´re using a from action is the best option otherwise header http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: `header('Location: nextPage.php');` before any HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

You can force redirect with successful headers like as below:

```
header("Location: second.php");
```

Comment: From what I've seen, the header needs to be put first, however I want some php code to run first THEN a redirect to happen. Is this possible?

Comment: @MandyLB, yes, is possible, the only requirement is to haven't any HTML output before `header()` call.

Answer (score 0):

In a well designed web application, there is no direct relation between the script and the page as the control script is the same for every page and simply shows the page needed based on what was selected or done.

There are many ways to implement this but a good starting point would be to look at MVC design.

Answer (score 0):

set the URL of new page on `form action=''` to load the another script after submit the form.